# Implementing multi tenant data structure using multiple schemas or by customerId table column

Tags: postgresql, database-design, multi-tenant

I am developing multi tenant store web application (software as a service) which will be used by many customers. I would like to use just one database. I would appreciate suggestions/feedback on how to go about this in the database:

1. Separate schemas for each customer. Whenever new customer signs up, I create separate schema.
2. Single schema with all the customers. And creating a CUSTOMER table with customerId that is referenced in all other tables (eg. orders, payments, etc). Whenever new customer signs up, I create an entry in CUSTOMER table.

Incase if you want to know what technologies are being used:
Postgres, Spring Boot MVC, REST, Maven, JPA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are major tradeoffs here.  With customer id's your foreign keys become more complex (the customer id should probably be a part of every foreign key) and that means additional indexes.  It also means you have to have some means of enforcing this restriction.  The big issue is that bugs in your application can quite easily disclose material from other customers.

With multiple schemas you have an issue that you have many more tables and this can cause performance problems for pg_dump in particular.  However with appropriate search paths it is a bit harder to compromise other clients' data.  However this is harder to use with a connection pool.

In general I think the schema approach is better because you can always scale out by partitioning by customer set, and the better security is important.  However it means you must have a good understanding of search_path and set it to a sensible value on every database transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. Another advantage we see is that each customer will have its own data in a separate schema and it will be beneficial in future. But the schema approach will put more work on my web app. We will just have a single web app deployed on tomcat so whenever a user logs in, the web app need to search which schema it belongs to. So we also need a shared table in public schema which does this finding. Don't you think it will be an overkill for a web app??

Comment: It's probably less work than building it into every query correctly.  Also you can cache the user/schema mapping in the middleware.